# python ticketing system, use dictionary or list inside list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, datetime, time

Hello wonderful people!
I am doing some python tutorials lately and this one is kinda out of my ability...

I made this logic but it seems like "import time" does not support plus or minus and made me couldn't code.

```
1. Break logs by space and save in a list

2. Save per request

3. person with "leave" goes to ticketing failed list

-Ignore if who is already on the list of ticketing succeeded list

4. 9 o'clock start

5. person who Requested first goes to waiting list

6. person who Requested later but in one minute goes to ticketing failed list

7. After a minute the person in waiting list goes to ticketing succeeded list

8. empty waiting list 

9. Back to 1

-If a ticketing succeeded person makes another request, ignore it

10. End the loop at 10 o'clock

11. Sort id in order

12. Return answer
```

could anyone find the answer or give me a hint for this question?

### Here is the question!

we decided to create ticketing system.

When the total number of tickets totalTicket and the log arrangement logs for access/cancellation are given, refer to the simulation description below and apply for ticketing.
Complete the solution method to extract and return the ID list of successful users.

Simulation description
Request log is left when connection is attempted, and leave log is left when connection is terminated within 1 minute after connection.
(Purchase failure after request at 09:00:00 and leave at 09:00:59, purchase success when request at 09:00:00 and leave at 09:01:00)
If one user is already connected, other users cannot connect and must try to connect again.
To purchase a ticket, you need to keep 1 minute after connecting to the server.
Users who successfully purchase tickets can access but cannot purchase again.

```
case 1
Woni, who made a request at 09:12:29, stayed connected for 1 minute and successfully purchased the ticket.
case 2
Brown, who requested at 09:23:11, could not maintain the connection for 1 minute and terminated the connection at 09:23:44, leaving a leave log and failing to purchase a ticket.
case 3
jason, jun, and cu tried to connect, but jason, who tried to connect the earliest, connected, and jun and cu that tried to connect after that failed to connect.

Purchase success
Request and maintain access for 1 minute when no user is purchasing (there is no leave log)

Purchase failure
If it fails to keep 1 minute after access (leave log exists)
When a request is made while another user is connected

Restrictions
Ticketing time is from 9:00 to 10:00. (The server shuts down at 10:00:0)
Logs of the same time (hour, minute, second) are not generated.
Logs have only request type and leave type.
The total number of tickets is an integer from 0 to 10,000.
id can only be in lowercase alphabets.
Please return the id in ascending order.

input
Total number of tickets
Connection attempt/cancellation log array (id, action[request/leave], hour, minute, second hh:mm:ss)

input sample
totalTicket = 2000
logs = [
    "woni request 09:12:29",
    "brown request 09:23:11",
    "brown leave 09:23:44",
    "jason request 09:33:51",
    "jun request 09:33:56",
    "cu request 09:34:02"
]

Print
ID array for successful ticketing

output sample
[
    "jason",
    "woni"
]
```

Comment: this is scheduling problem, [lottery schedulling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_scheduling) this may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tidied a few things up regarding your other, closed question, and left comments in the code below. The main thing was factoring out the time parsing into a function as it is done repeatedly in your code. I have started on your use of arbitrary constants by naming your start and end times but have not gone on to reduce the use of list indices. I would also take a look at the use of list type for name success should it be a set as you test wether line[0] is `in` success.

```
from datetime import time

# Name some constants
start_time = time(9, 0, 0)
end_time = time(9, 59, 0)

logs = [
    "woni request 09:12:29",
    "brown request 09:23:11",
    "brown leave 09:23:44",
    "jason request 09:33:51",
    "jun request 09:33:56",
    "cu request 09:34:02"        
]

# Refactor repeated action as function
def to_hms(text):
    time_sections = text.split(':')
    hms = [int(t) for t in time_sections]
    return hms

def solution(logs):
    line =[]
    process = []
    success = []

    for i in logs:        
        line = i.split(' ')
        if line[0] in success:
            continue

        h, m, s = to_hms(line[2])
        if time(h, m, s) > start_time:
            if process:     # '!= []' unnecessary
                if line[1] == 'leave':
                    process = []
                elif line[1] == 'request':
                    h2, m2, s2 = to_hms(process[2])
                    m2 += 1
                    if time(h2, m2, s2) <= time(h, m, s):
                        success.append(process[0])  # its a str
                        process = line
            if line[1] == 'request':
                process = line
    if logs[-1] == process[0]:
        h3, m3, s3 = to_hms(process[2])
        if time(h3, m3, s3) <= end_time:
            success.append(process[0])
    else:
        success.append(process[0])

    return success


print(solution(logs))
```